# Blank select option #ngValue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-value

How can I avoid blank option in the form output?

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="item.type" >
                                <option ng-value="0">Real</option>
                                <option ng-value="1">Fake</option>
                                <option ng-value="2">Both</option>
                            </select>
```

item.type is set in the controller

The issue slightly different from what I saw in similar topics because of usage of ng-value and the fact, that value of item.type is already set

**Edit**: Changing `ng-value` to `value` solved the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "blank line"?  Do you mean a blank entry option) in the select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is item.type set in the controller? 
 
The blank line is the current value of item.type. If you set it as an object in the controller, it's normal to be shown that way. Try setting it to one of the 3 choices you have like this:

```
   angular.module('yourModule').controller('ctrl', function($scope)){
       $scope.item = {}; //edited
       $scope.item.type = "1"; // or 2, or 0
   }
```

This is how angular handles two-way databinding. If the value of your item.type does not match any of the options, it is normal to add another blank line.

EDIT:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="item.type" >
    <option value="0">Real</option>
    <option value="1">Fake</option>
    <option value="2">Both</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Also, you can add an option for handling null (blank) values.  <option value="">Unknown</option>

Comment: I also tried to <option value="">Unknown</option>, but it only increased options list. The initial value still balnk

Comment: @BaviGurunath - what is the value of $scope.item.type?  It must be something not in your options

Comment: @jbrown it's '1', which is string value

Comment: @BaviGurunath - Ok, then I'm stumped.  You'll need to put up a plunker for us to see the whole picture and help you.

Comment: @BaviGurunath Please note that if $scope.item has not been instantiated as an object, it will not work. Example:
       `$scope.item = {}; // VERY IMPORTANT` and after that 
       `$scope.item.type = "1"; `

Comment: @BaviGurunath Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CgeFpDDNHXK24JpF5vp6?p=preview) with a working example: I also had to change `ng-value` to `value`. It seems that it was causing an unexpected behaviour. Anyway, It's better to keep your options on the controller's scope as an array and just use `ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions'` to generate them. It also keeps your html alot cleaner.

Comment: Changing ng-value to value solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem of blank option is due to the ng-model is not matching with the ng-option values. Could you just print the value of item.type in view using {{item.type}}.

Make the following changes.

In controller set the item.type as

$scope.item = {};
$scope.item.type = "1";

make the following changes in html.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="item.type" >
                            <option value="0">Real</option>
                            <option value="1">Fake</option>
                            <option value="2">Both</option>
                        </select>
```

Comment: Do you mean {{item.type}}? It shows '1'. And, yes, values of item.type are strings. I assume it cause the problem, but I can't figure out how to fix it